# is it possible to develop an app in iphone which will hang up the outgoing call say after 5 seconds

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to develop an app in iphone which will alert  and hang up the outgoing call say after 5 seconds. Automatically redial a monitored call that was ended by the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not. The SDK currently only allows you to initiate calls