# Auto Redial using iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speaker

Two questions actually.

***First*** : I know iPhone is missing auto-redialing functionality but is there any other way to achieve it by iPhone application, as I can call by my application but facing problem cannot **auto redial**.

***Second*** : Before calling I want to implement functionality of loud-speaker on a button action.

Is there any way to achieve the above 2 functionalities?

I spent 4-5 hours on googgling about it and the result is only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847859/is-it-possible-to-develop-an-app-in-iphone-which-will-hang-up-the-outgoing-call)

I go through to  [apples doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html) and found some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319805/detecting-call-state-in-ios4)and also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274642/unhiding-a-view-is-very-slow-in-ctcallcenter-calleventhandler) but cant get the right way to implement above functions ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Second case it's definitely NO.
But for the First case, I have no sure about this, but can be tried:

1. Subscribe with the CTCallCenter for call states notifications and use some background application type (voip, location or audio) or use some waiting block, that will allow to prevent going to suspended state as long as possible
2. Open URL using tel://
3. If the call notification about call failure comes in, try to repeat opening an URL

Once again, just an idea, may not work at all :/

Comment: Yes After a long search i came to know that this is the only way to implement AutoRedial, but i drop this feature from my application pls let me know if you have any sample code for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those actions are possible with the SDK.